# onSystemUiVisibilityChange listener not called after rotation as should

Tags: android, navbar, android-immersive

im pulling my hair on this. What I want to do is system ui + my views toggling with total fullscreen (statusbar and navbar hidden + immersive_sticky)

-- By default I want the ui to be hidden, i.e. just content showing. This seems to be a ridiculous problem

*On first activity onCreate everything seems to work. **After I rotate and call hide again, onSystemUiVisibilityChange does not get called even though mDecorView.getSystemUiVisibility() and argument flags being set dont match...***. As if system cached the last value somewhere and then because its the same,  does not trigger the listener .. sounds reasonable, right? so I call syncChrome manually with last visibility value from bundle. Now UI is hidden or shown after rotation corretly. HOWEVER, now if I toggle it, system bars come back as should, but the listener is not called!!!! If I toggle it one more time, everything goes away as should, and if I toggle it one more time, it fixes it self and works (both system ui and my ui is shown correctly)... so basically after 3 toggles it starts to work as expected -____-

One idea was to not change the system visibility after rotation, just sync chrome .. nope, if I ommit setting the HIDE_FLAGS, then system bars are shown .. so it doesnt remember the last values as it did in the case above...

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

*(I could not care about the system ui listener and manually show / hide my ui manually, **however there is a glitch, when hide() is called in onCreate, and then I toggle to show the system ui, the navbar and status bar both have weirdly transparent background, even though theyre supposed to have color --** if I toggle it off and on again then navbar / statusbar color comes back as should)*

...Banging my head so hard...

```
public class UiHider {

    private static final String KEY_WAS_HIDDEN = "was_hidden";

    private static final int INIT_FLAGS =
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

    private static final int HIDE_FLAGS =
            SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // Hides nav bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // Hides status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY; // Makes it not come back when touched

    private View mDecorView;
    private View[] mChromeViews;

    public UiHider(Window window) {
        mDecorView = Preconditions.checkNotNull(window.getDecorView());
    }

    public void prepareStableLayout() {
        mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(INIT_FLAGS);
        mDecorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
            @Override public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                syncChrome((visibility & SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) == 0, false);
            }
        });
    }

    public void init(Bundle savedInstanceState, View... chromeViews) {
        mToolbar = toolbar;
        mChromeViews = chromeViews;

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            hideUi();
        } else {
            if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_WAS_HIDDEN, false)) {
                hideUi();
                syncChrome(false, true);
            } else {
                showUi();
                syncChrome(true, true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void toggle() {
        if (isHidden()) {
            showUi();
        } else {
            hideUi();
        }
    }

    public void showUi() {
        mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(mDecorView.getSystemUiVisibility() & ~HIDE_FLAGS);
    }

    public void hideUi() {
        mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(mDecorView.getSystemUiVisibility() | HIDE_FLAGS);
    }

    private void syncChrome(boolean show, boolean immediate) {
        // ... setVisibility VISIBLE or GONE to mChromeViews 
    }

    private boolean isHidden() {
        return (mDecorView.getSystemUiVisibility() & HIDE_FLAGS) == HIDE_FLAGS;
    }

}



public class ReaderActivity extends Activity {

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.foo);

        mUiHider = new UiHider(getWindow());
        mUiHider.prepareStableLayout();
        mUiHider.init(savedInstanceState, mToolbar);
    }

    @Override public void onBodyClicked(int globalPageIndex) {
        mUiHider.toggle();
    }

    @Override protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mUiHider.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Comment: `    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) ` maybe can help you.

Comment: what about it please?

Comment: I think you can do something when activity's focus changes . For example  focus  changed  from false to ture, you can hide system bar

Comment: I know, but my problem is rotations